# how to avoid circular references and write DRY code in django

Tags: python, django, dry, circular-reference

Whenever I create DRY functions that I can reuse later and then use them in models, I get circular references;

For example:

I have the following models:

```
from social.services import get_top_viewed_posts

class Post(models.Model):  
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField('Post Title', max_length=255) 

class ActivityUpdateEmail(models.Model):
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):        

        posts = get_top_viewed_posts()
```

My top viewed posts function is another file called services.py so I can access it other places. It looks like:

```
from social.models import Post

def get_top_viewed_posts():
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        pk__in=popular_posts_ids,
        ).order_by(
                '-created_at'
                )

    return posts
```

Then I get the error:

> ```
> services.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from social.models import Post
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Post'
> ```

If I change it to:

transactions = Action.objects.filter(
        content_type__pk=35,
        created_at__gte=start_date,
        ).values_list('object_id', flat=True)

```
popular_posts_ids = []
popular_posts = Counter(transactions).most_common()[:result_amount]

for dic in popular_posts:
    popular_posts_ids.append(dic[0])


class ActivityUpdateEmail(models.Model):
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def send(self):  

         posts = Post.objects.filter(
              pk__in=popular_posts_ids,
         ).order_by(
            '-created_at'
            )
```

This works no problem.

How can I use this dry approach of abstracting functionality, and then being able to use them in my models?

Comment: Looks more like an import path error than a circular import error. What are the application folder layout and Python version?

Comment: @PauloScardine it is python 3.6.

Comment: If both `models.py` and the other file are in the same folder, have you tried something like `from .models import Post` ?

Comment: I added from .models import Post but it still gets the same compilation error

Comment: I always get annoyed at imports, but if you're doing from social.services import shouldn't you be doing from social.models instead of .models?

Comment: Move the import statement from the top of `models.py` to the method where you are using `get_top_viewed_posts`.

Comment: I agree that it's not a circular error. Is there an `__init__.py` file in the directory?

Comment: It is not a circular import error, it is an import order error. By the time she is importing `get_top_viewed_posts` the `Post` class is not declared yet.

Comment: Wow!!! @PauloScardine moving the import to the method works!

Comment: There are other alternatives, check my answer.

Comment: And sorry for using "she", read the name as "Alma" - a common female name in Portuguese/Spanish. I guess I need new glasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because when you import `get_top_viewed_posts` at the top of `models.py` the `Post` model is not declared yet.

You have a few alternatives.

### Move the import from the top of `models.py` to inside the method

```
def send(self):        
    from social.services import get_top_viewed_posts
    posts = get_top_viewed_posts()
```

Don't worry about performance, imports are cached - but if you use it in other methods it may be tedious to repeat the same import over and over.

### Abstract the class

Make the function more generic passing the model as an argument, this way you don't need to import the model in the top of the `services.py` file:

```
def get_top_viewed_model(model, popular_ids, order_by='-created_at'):
    return model.objects..filter(
        pk__in=popular_ids,
    ).order_by(
        order
    )
```

Then:

```
def send(self):        
    posts = get_top_viewed_model(type(self), popular_posts_ids)

# at other places
get_top_viewed_model(Posts, popular_posts_ids)
```

### Use a custom manager

Create a custom manager with a `top_viewed` method:

```
class TopViewedManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, order='-created_at', **kwargs):
        self._order = order
        self._filter = kwargs

    def top_viewed(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(**self._filter).order_by(self._order)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = TopViewedManager(pk__in=popular_posts_ids)
```

Then just use this where you would use `get_top_viewed_model`:

```
Post.objects.top_viewed()
```

This manager is quite generic so you can use it with any model, filter and order you want.

Probably there are other alternatives and it is a matter of personal taste.